# How to vectorize looking up the row index of one dataframe based on conditions from rows in another dataframe

Tags: pandas, vectorization

I have two pandas dataframes with the same columns, eg

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0,1,1], 'B':[0,1,0,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1], 'B':[1,1]})
```

And I want to return the row index from df1 where the values match the rows in df2. eg, yielding [1, 3]. I could do this by looping over df2, but in practice this is really slow. What is the correct way to vectorize this operation in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `merge` first

```
out = df1.reset_index().merge(df2,how='right')['index']
Out[63]: 
0    1
1    3
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.

Comment: @wthrift yw :-) if this is what you need would like consider accept ?

Comment: Sorry about that! I haven't asked many questions yet.

Comment: @wthrift yw :-) happy coding